# ModSecurity Block Multiple URLs with One Rule?

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I was wondering if there is a way to block multiple URLs with a single rule in ModSecurity? I have a list of 30+ URLs I would like to deny and log. I know I can block a single URL with a command such as:

SecRule REQUEST_URI "/url/to/block" "phase:1,id:'1000001',log,noauditlog,deny,status:403"

Do I need to write a rule for each URL or can they all be combined into the same rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a couple of choices to avoid multiple rules:

Have a really long rule using [regex](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#rx) or [pm](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#pm). For example:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pm url1 url2 url3...etc." \
"phase:1,id:'1000001',log,noauditlog,deny,status:403"
```

Or list the URLs in a file and use [pmFromFile](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#pmFromFile) to do the matching. For example:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pmFromFile /path/to/urlBlacklistFile" \
 "phase:1,id:'1000001',log,noauditlog,deny,status:403"
```

Comment: The @pmFromFile method worked great. One note, I did have to change from a status:403 to a redirect as the server was catching the nonexistent URL before ModSecurity and redirecting on it's own. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pmFromFile /path/to/urlBlacklistFile" \
 "phase:1,id:'1000001',log,noauditlog,deny,status:403"
```

and not just @pm